# Full Text Search Exact Match with Stop Words

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search, stop-words, exact-match

I implement the Full Text Search and have a stop list contains words "is" and "here", when I run the first query, it return the exact same number of results as the second query. I know it will transform the keywords when a stop word is found when I apply this setting

```
EXEC sp_configure 'transform noise words', 1
```

1. SELECT * FROM dbo.Tracks t 
   WHERE t.accountid = 27 AND CONTAINS(t.searchterms, '"summer is here"')
2. SELECT * FROM dbo.Tracks t 
   WHERE t.accountid = 27 AND CONTAINS(t.searchterms, '"summer"')

My question is, is there a way to keep the stop word list as it is and search on "summer is here" exact phrase at the same time?

Comment: See this question: [Full text search does not work if stop word is included even though stop word list is empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12759042/full-text-search-does-not-work-if-stop-word-is-included-even-though-stop-word-li). The solution mentioned there was to create an empty stoplist and use it in the FTS indexes, so there are no stop words at all.