# Why is SQL Server full-text search not matching numbers?

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search, contains, containstable

I'm using SQL Server 2014 Express, and have a full-text index setup on a table.

The full-text index only indexes a single column, in this example named `foo`.

The table has 3 rows in it. The values in the 3 rows, for that full-text indexed column are like so ...

```
test 1
test 2
test 3 test 1
```

Each new line above is a new row in the table, and that text is literally what is in the full-text indexed column. So, using SQL Server's `CONTAINS` function, if I perform the following query, I get all rows back as matches, as expected.

```
SELECT * FROM example WHERE CONTAINS(foo, 'test')
```

But, if I run the following query, I also get all of the rows back as matches, which I am not expecting. In the following query, I only expected one row as a match.

```
SELECT * FROM example WHERE CONTAINS(foo, '"test 3"')
```

Lastly, simply searching for "3" returns no matching rows, which I also did not expect. I'd expect one matching row from the following query, but get none.

```
SELECT * FROM example WHERE CONTAINS(foo, '3')
```

I've read the MSDN pages on `CONTAINS` and full-text indexing, but I can't figure out this behavior. I must be doing something wrong.

Would anybody be able to explain to me what's happening and how to perform the searches I've described?

Comment: I suspect numbers are stop words - not indexed.

Comment: I suspect stop words are to blame either too short or frequently used.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12759042/full-text-search-does-not-work-if-stop-word-is-included-even-though-stop-word-li

Comment: Ah yup, stop-words it is. Thanks for that link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While this may not be *the* answer, it solved my original question. My full-text index was using the system stop list. For whatever reason, certain individual numbers, such as "1" in "test 1", were being skipped or whatever the stop list does.

The following question and answer, here on SO, suggested disabling the stop list alltogether. I did this and now my full text searches match as I expected them to, at the expense of a larger full text index, it looks like.

[Full text search does not work if stop word is included even though stop word list is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12759042/full-text-search-does-not-work-if-stop-word-is-included-even-though-stop-word-li)