# FTS right join in view with ISNULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create View with a left (or right) join for Full-Text Search, and obviously you cannot. I have tried to join using `IsNull`, but not working.

How would I create a query, that would go in a view that has a right/left join for FTS?

```
CREATE TABLE #Tline
(
  Id int Primary Key, 
  [name] varchar(255) null
)
GO

Insert into #Tline (id,name) Values(1,'test 1')
Insert into #Tline (id,name) Values(2,'test 2')
Insert into #Tline (id,name) Values(3,'test 3')
Insert into #Tline (id,name) Values(4,'test 4')
Insert into #Tline (id,name) Values(5,'test 5')
GO

CREATE TABLE #Task (Id int Primary Key, TlineId int null)
GO

Insert into #Task (id,TlineId) Values(1,2)
Insert into #Task (id,TlineId) Values(2,3)
Insert into #Task (id,TlineId) Values(3,4)
GO

SELECT 
  #Tline.Id, #Task.Id
FROM 
  #Tline 
  JOIN #Task ON #Tline.Id = ISNULL(#Task.TlineId,0)
GO

DROP 
  TABLe #Tline
DROP 
  TABLe #Task
GO
```

Comment: If you are trying to create a view, I would expect `CREATE VIEW` in the code.  That said, I still don't know what your question is.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Updated the questions accordingly

Comment: I'd expect to see [`contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in the `on` clause. Aside: FTS doesn't tend to work well with numeric data. ([This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739687/why-is-sql-server-full-text-search-not-matching-numbers) is one example.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want all rows from `#Tline` with matching tasks:

```
SELECT l.Id, t.Id
FROM #Tline l LEFT JOIN
     #Task t
     ON l.Id = t.TlineId;
```

That seems like a reasonable query given the data you have provided.

Comment: Yes that would work in a normal query but won't work when creating a view with unique index. (of course this is for FTS)