# T-SQL CONTAINS having problems with fulltext index on computed column with a long number

Tags: sql-server-2012, full-text-search, contains

I have a computed field with a full-text index on it. It's working properly except for just a few records out of thousands, and why remains a mystery:

[fake name]

`JAMES J BRATWURST LTDJ LCHM LCDAA1 ACD  1215041803 111.223.3333`

A select-query with

... `where CONTAINS(searchname,'bratwurst')`

works fine, and

...  `where CONTAINS(searchname,'111.223.3333')`

works fine too.   But

... `where CONTAINS(searchname,'1215041803')`  does not return anything.

Edit: this wildcard search works too (which shows that the index has been populated):

..  `where CONTAINS(searchname, '"121504180*"')`.

*Yet on other similar records, searching the searchname column for a 10-digit "number" using CONTAINS does return values.* So it's not that the full-text tokenizer is ignoring numbers.

Thinking that it was possibly a [stoplist issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12759042/full-text-search-does-not-work-if-stop-word-is-included-even-though-stop-word-li), I turned `stoplist` off and repopulated the index, but to no avail.

I am open to suggestions for other things to check! Thanks

Comment: I feel like there's something goofy going on here, like a carriage return or something after that value in the original column. Granted I wouldn't think that would matter, but can you test by inserting a duplicate row (with a new PK val of course) or check the leading and trailing unicode with `select unicode(yourColumn) select unicode(reverse(yourColumn))`

Comment: Goofy indeed. Thanks for the unicode suggestion, but nothing unusual. The string of numbers is using codepoints from the normal ASCII digits range. The 10-digit number is concatenated into the computed column's varchar string as `+ convert(varchar(10),[myColumn])`

Comment: I am having this exact issue - really odd