# SQL Contains not getting results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search

I have the string "safari no douro 4x4 atividade".

Why can't i get results from this query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE where CONTAINS(column,'4x4')
```

but i get results with:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE where column like '%4x4%'
```

Any other word on that string gets me results.
Full-Text-Index fully working.

Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.5057.00 (X64)

Comment: `4x4` is probably not included in the full text index, either because it is too short or because it starts with a number.

Comment: ...so disable the stop list? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12759042/full-text-search-does-not-work-if-stop-word-is-included-even-though-stop-word-li

Comment: i think its because it starts with a number, but how can i work around that?